# Gem bundle throws wrong argument type error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.kartar.net/2009/12/yes-mum-ill-behave-beginning-behaviour-driven-infrastructure/) and I get the following error which turns up no google results and I'm still too inexperienced to know how to fix it.  Any suggestions?

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc)

I am not even sure what gem bundle does exactly so I am not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving over to my Windows PC to move forward with the tutorial.  My macbook was throwing errors on almost every GEM installation so I gave up on trying to use ruby on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the error but follow the projects documentation and see if it fixes it: http://github.com/auxesis/cucumber-nagios

As the documentation says `gem bundle` comes from bundler gem.